# How to refresh the DataTable

Tags: jquery, database, datatables

I have using data from server side to the DataTable. When i click the some action in table, that row want to be delete. Then Referesh the table.

DataTable

```
DataTable = $('#DataTable').dataTable({
"sAjaxSource": "php/pendingApprovals.php",
"bRetrieve":true,
"bSortClasses": false,
...
...
});
```

When i clik the action in table, row will be deleted. This is by server side processing. and

```
DataTable.fnDraw();
DataTable._fnAjaxUpdate();
DataTableFun();
```

Here one issue is there.

if i use "bServerSide" , Search box doesn't work.

If i not use "bServerSide", that row was deleted, but remianing rows are hide. When i click on TH, then remaining rows are shown. What is the issue there.. I cant find the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are looking for `fnReloadAjax()`

Refer the below link.

http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnReloadAjax